# User Profile Service Application page cannot be opened

Tags: web-services, user-profile-service, userprofile-sync

When I try to access the User Profile Service Application page, it shows the 'Something went wrong' error. Also the user profile sync service cannot be started as it keep being stuck in starting.

This issue occurs after the server has been infected by ransomware. After the cleanup, I deleted and recreated the service application several times but still the page cannot be accessed and the UPS sync service keep stuck on starting/stopping.

In the event viewer error logs are showing:

> [FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase, ' C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\Profile\
>   Profilepropertyservice.svc & ProfileDBCacheService.svc', was invalid.]
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.BeginProcessRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +0
>   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +556    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause:

Incorrect entry in Profilepropertyservice.svc & ProfileDBCacheService.svc located at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\WebServices\Profile

Solution:

- Add in Local Security Policy for spadmin Allow log on locally, Impersonate a client after authentication, Log on as a batch jobs
- Correct the entry as below:

->ProfileDBCacheService.svc

```
<%@ServiceHost 
  Language="c#"

  Service="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileDBCacheService, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
  Factory="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileDBCacheServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
%>
```

->ProfilePropertyService.svc

```
<%@ServiceHost 
  Language="c#" 

  Service="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyService, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" 
  Factory="Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfilePropertyServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"
%>
```

- The UPS page can now be accessed
- Change startup type for FIM service to automatic
- Noticed one time timer job created for profilesynchronizationsetupjob getting created again after deleting it
- Ran below script to fix the timer service

> $farm = Get-SPFarm  $FarmTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances 
>   foreach ($FT in $FarmTimers){write-host "Server: "
>   $FT.Server.Name.ToString(); write-host "Status: " $FT.status;
>   write-host "Allow Service Jobs: " $FT.AllowServiceJobs; write-host
>   "Allow Content DB Jobs: " $FT.AllowContentDatabaseJobs;"`n"}
>   $disabledTimers = $farm.TimerService.Instances | where {$_.Status -ne
>   "Online"}  if ($disabledTimers -ne $null)  {foreach ($timer in
>   $disabledTimers)  {Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "Timer service
>   instance on server " $timer.Server.Name " is NOT Online. Current
>   status:" $timer.Status  Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Attempting
>   to set the status of the service instance to online..."  $timer.Status
>   = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPObjectStatus]::Online  $timer.Update()  write-host -ForegroundColor Red "You MUST now go
>   restart the SharePoint timer service on server " $timer.Server.Name}} 
>   else{Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green  "All Timer Service Instances
>   in the farm are online. No problems found!"}

- Finally, the FIM service got started and UPS sync service is up and running